# File Transfer using FTP

Tags: c#

I need to transfer a big file using FTP in my Windows application to remote machine.

I used command prompt to transfer files using FTP. But how can I do it programmatically

in .net 2.0. Sample program is advantage.

Answer (score 4):

For this you could use: FtpWebRequest.

Here is a great example. I hate linking to another site, but it has an example with it for uploading and downloading using FTP.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/neo_matrix/simpleftp01172007082222am/simpleftp.aspx