# How to create windows server using C# to transfer files via FTP

Tags: c#, .net

How to create windows server using C# to transfer files via FTP? I have a folder that every x minutes are feeded by xml files that my ERP system generates...  I need to send to my extern server via FTP. I think running a windows service every 30 minutes and loop through all files on this folder and sending via FTP is enough. Can you help me? Any exemples? Using .net vs2k8 is my development envronment. Thank you very much

Comment: Your question is broad. What part are you having problems with? What have you got so far? This is something you could do easily with a scheduled batch file.

Comment: If you only need help with the Ftp client code - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264326/file-transfer-using-ftp

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://....");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","...");

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("testfile.txt");
            byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            response.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

How to transfer the file is in the answer from Aghilas

I would create it as a Service so you can have it auto start

Rather than poll the directory you can just use

[FileSystemWatcher Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.aspx)

Maybe log any failed uploads